# CRM Workflows keep failing when calling a child workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

When I create a CRM workflow which has actions to fire child workflows, the workflow keeps failing.

The weird thing is that I can run workflows with no child workflows fine, just happens when other workflows are triggered from within another one.
Has anyone encountered this before and if so, does anyone know how to fix it.
I am getting errors with this.  The error we are getting is:

> Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.StartChildWorkflow.InputParameters'.

The full stack error is :

> Unhandled Exception: System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException: Cannot set unknown member 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.StartChildWorkflow.InputParameters'.
>      at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember property)
>      at System.Xaml.XamlServices.Transform(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlWriter xamlWriter, Boolean closeWriter)
>      at System.Activities.XamlIntegration.FuncFactory`1.Evaluate()
>      at System.Activities.DynamicActivity.OnInternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings)
>      at System.Activities.Activity.InternalCacheMetadata(Boolean createEmptyBindings, IList`1& validationErrors)
>      at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivity(ChildActivity childActivity, ChildActivity& nextActivity, Stack`1& activitiesRemaining, ActivityCallStack parentChain, IList`1& validationErrors, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback)
>      at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.ProcessActivityTreeCore(ChildActivity currentActivity, ActivityCallStack parentChain, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
>      at System.Activities.ActivityUtilities.CacheRootMetadata(Activity activity, LocationReferenceEnvironment hostEnvironment, ProcessActivityTreeOptions options, ProcessActivityCallback callback, IList`1& validationErrors)
>      at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.ValidateWorkflow(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.EnsureInitialized()
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Enqueue(InstanceOperation operation, Boolean push)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.WaitForTurn(InstanceOperation operation, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.InternalRun(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isUserRun)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ActivityHost.StartWorkflowExecution(Activity workflow, ICommonWorkflowContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.ActivityHostBase.StartWorkflow(ICommonWorkflowContext context, Activity preLoadedActivity)

Bear in mind, these are not XAML workflows, they are generic CRM workflows which contain no custom Workflow activities.

I have been looking at this for about a week now, and the only references I see are infinite loop workflows, which is not the case here and custom XAML workflows, which again, is not the case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The system this is running on is CRM 2013 SP1 Rollup 2

Thanks in advance

Comment: The calling of the child workflow seems to be problematic.  A few questions: 1) is the child workflow set to be available to run as a child process?  2) how are you calling the child workflow from the parent workflow? Is the child workflow triggered by an action that is performed by the parent workflow, or is it directly calling it?  3) can you post the screenshot of both the parent and child workflow?  4) is this all happening in your dev environment, or did you move the code and its not working in some secondary environment?

Comment: Is this an upgraded organization ? If you create a blank new organization and try to build the same workflow, does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I found the solution to the issue here.
The issue was that All the servers were not on the same version.
The two front end servers were on SP1, yet the Async servers were not.
As child workflows are not compatible cross SP, this is what was causing the issues.
After updating the async servers, everything started working.
Sorry guys and Thanks